# Deserialize json with converter

Tags: .net, json, json.net, converters, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize some json into a .net class:

```
{"reset": true, "cursor": "xxxx", "has_more": true, "entries": [
    ["/ict", {
        "revision": 22,
        "rev": "16010e2631",
        "thumb_exists": false,
        "bytes": 0,
        "modified": "Sat, 11 Sep 2010 00:11:24 +0000",
        "path": "/ICT",
        "is_dir": true,
        "size": "0 bytes"
    }],
    ["/ict/docs", {
        "revision": 1772,
        "rev": "6ec010e2631",
        "thumb_exists": false,
        "bytes": 0,
        "modified": "Wed, 15 Sep 2010 09:55:24 +0000",
        "path": "/ICT/Docs",
        "is_dir": true,
        "size": "0 bytes"
    }]
]}
```

I'm having trouble with the entries part, each array starts with a string but it has no key. The class it should be deserialized to looks like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(DeltaEntryConverter))]  
public class DeltaEntry
{                
    public string Path { get; set; }        
    public MetaData MetaData { get; set; }
}
```

I was thinking to use a jsonConverter but I'm not sure how to deserialize the object (the second index in each array) to the metadata class if I use a converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the object you want to convert, you can use the `ToObject<T>()` to get the converted object.  In your case, you want to convert the second item in the array to a `MetaData` object.

```
public class DeltaEntryConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var arr = (JArray)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        return new DeltaEntry
        {
            Path = (string)arr[0],
            MetaData = arr[1].ToObject<MetaData>(),
        };
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just noticed there's a nicer way to convert to the `MetaData` object. Use the `ToObject<T>()` method.

Comment: It's more readable indeed, but internally it works the same right?

Comment: Yes, it should all be the same. Except you don't need to convert the object back to a string as an intermediate step.